# Is there a way to express a generic handler in a generic way in C#?

Tags: c#

Imagine I have an interface that specifies some collection handler:

```
interface ICollectionHandler<T> where T : new() { ... }
```

I then have same other class that wants a collection handler, which it will use for various types, so I want to do something like:

```
class SomeClass<T> where T : ICollectionHandler<> ...
```

If I do this though, I get an error saying that the "Type argument is missing".

So is there a way of specifying that T is a generic type, whose own type argument can be specified at runtime, or am I pushing C# beyond its (possibly sensible) boundaries here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a base interface for `ICollectionHandler<T>` and constrain against it.

```
interface ICollectionHandler { ... }
interface ICollectionHandler<T> : ICollectionHandler where T : new() { ... }
class SomeClass<T> where T : ICollectionHandler { ... }
```

Or add a parameter to `SomeClass` representing the Type that should be passed into the `ICollectionHandler<T>` constraint:

```
class SomeClass<T, U> where T : ICollectionHandler<U> { ... }
```

Comment: It's taken me two years, but having come back to this question, as I read it, I thought to myself "You needed SomeClass<T1, T2>". You told me that two years ago, so have a belated correct answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like:

```
interface ICollectionHandler<T> where T : new() { }

public class MyImplementation<T, U> where T : ICollectionHandler<U> { }
```

I'm pretty sure that knowing which generic type reside inside your implementation of your interface is required. If you don't care about that sub-type:

```
interface ICollectionHandler { }

public abstract class CollectionHandler<T> : ICollectionHandler where T : new()  { }

public class MyImplementation<T> where T : ICollectionHandler { }
```

But it really depends how you are gonna use that and in what context. Maybe you can give more details?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a second type parameter to `SomeClass`:

```
class SomeClass<T, U> where T : ICollectionHandler<U> ...
```

Comment: I don't think that would work for me as I then have to (a) specify U when creating an instance of SomeClass, and (b) in the process constrain T to be T<U> only. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Yes, you would have to specify both types.